# Binding error when binding CollectionViewSource to custom ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a written a control but I am having some issues binding a CollectionViewSource to my ItemsSource property. If I Bind an ObservableCollection to the ItemsSource property everything works as expected. With the CollectionViewSource bound to it I get the following binding error in the output.

Error: Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView' to type 'IBindableIterable'; BindingExpression: Path='JobView.View' DataItem='App.ViewModel.MainViewModel'; target element is MySpecialControl.MySpecialControl' (Name='null'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IBindableIterable').

```
public sealed class MySpecialControl: Control
{
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MySpecialControl), new PropertyMetadata((IEnumerable)null, OnItemSourcePropertyChanged));

    private static void OnItemSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MySpecialControl)sender).OnItemSourcePropertyChanged((IEnumerable)  eventAgrs.OldValue, (IEnumerable)eventAgrs.NewValue);
    }


    private void OnItemSourcePropertyChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        INotifyCollectionChanged oldCollectionChanged = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (oldCollectionChanged != null)
            oldCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= ItemSource_CollectionChanged;

        INotifyCollectionChanged newCollectionChanged = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (newCollectionChanged != null)
            newCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += ItemSource_CollectionChanged;
    }


   private void ItemSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

In my XAML I have bound it to the CollectionViewSource.View

Any ideas how to change the ItemsSource to accept an ObservableCollection as well as a CollectionViewSource.View ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you binding to? A `ListBox`?

Comment: It is a Bindable map component. The ItemsSource will be for the Points on the map.

Comment: There is a lot of code in `ItemsControl` for handling this sort of thing. It intrinsically understands collection views. You may want to consider extending `ItemsControl` instead of `Control` if it makes sense to generate child views for each item in the collection. As for the error you are seeing, it would help to see the code for the properties on both sides of the failed binding, as well as for the binding itself.

Comment: Looking at your error more closely, the namespace of the ICollectionView it is showing is not the one I would expect to see. It is a Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView (which is the type of the Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.CollectionViewSource.View property) instead of a System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView (which is the type of the System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.View property). I am wondering if you maybe got your namespace imports messed up somewhere?